# Grouping preserving order

Tags: scala, collections

I have the following trait:

```
trait Tr{
    val value: Int
}
```

and a non-ordered sequence:

```
val s: Seq[Tr] = //...
```

Now I want to split this sequence `s` by groups with the same `value` --
 `Seq[Seq[Tr]]` so that the resulting sequence is sorted by `value` in ascending order. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `s.groupBy(_.value).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)`